# Cannot load pixmap

Tags: windows, qt, windows-7, qpixmap

I'm trying to load image to pixmap. Image itself is added to resources. So here what I'm trying to do:

```
result = pixmap.load("Field/foreground.png");
```

result is always false. Image exists, I can get it's absolute path like this:

```
    QFile qfile("Field/foreground.png");
    QFileInfo qfileinfo(qfile);
    qDebug() << qfileinfo.absolutePath();
```

so path seems to be correct. And qt is running as admin. Any ideas?

PS I'm under Windows 7. The smae code was successfully tested on linux.

Comment: Use QFile::exists() to check if the file really exists instead of just looking the path.

Comment: Well, it apparently not. Thanks @Roku. I've just mixed up two directories. Could you give -1 to my question, please?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QFile::exists() to check if the file really exists instead of just looking the path.- @Roku